# Difference between HtmlResponse requests.response

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, request, response

I want to extract all the links to perfume brands of [this website webpage](https://www.nosetime.com/pinpai/2-a.html).

[image]

I would thought to do a scrapy scraper that finds all the href, like I did with BeautifulSoup:

```
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('https://www.nosetime.com'+ url, 
                                      headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')
    print(soup)
    result = soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'imgborder'})
    for r in result:
        brand_url = r.attrs['href']
```

[requests.get returns a Response object](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_requests_get.asp#:%7E:text=The%20get()%20method%20returns,Response%20object.) here

But this homemade technique crashes with merry 403 errors so I thought of making a scrapy scraper as this tutorial claims that it can handle these.

```
import scrapy
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class NosetimeScraper(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "nosetime"
    urls = ['/pinpai/2-a.html']
    start_urls = ['https://www.nosetime.com' + url for url in urls]

    def parse(self, response):
        # proceed to other pages of the listings
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
        results = soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'imgborder'})
        for r in results:
            brand_url = r.attrs['href']
            yield scrapy.Request(url=brand_url, callback=self.parse)

        # then do something with the scrapy.Request() response that has been yielded ...
```

But it returns:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
AttributeError: 'HtmlResponse' object has no attribute 'content'
```

So I guess there is a difference between HtmlResponse requests.response ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `scrapy.http.HtmlResponse` is different from `requests.models.Response`. You can use `response.body` instead.

But it would be much better to use `.css()` with Scrapy:

```
def parse(self, response):
    urls = response.css('a.imgborder::attr(href)').getall()
    for url in urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: Thanks, do you have a tutorial or resources on how scraping by CSS? I am more used to do so with beautifulsoup

Comment: Check out Mozilla's MDN docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors. You can always test your selectors in devtools by pressing F12. This is already enough for most sites but if you need more flexibility consider learning xpath too, it is called with `.xpath()`.